# How to point a URL to a static HTML through GCP API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am pretty much new to GoogleCloudPlatform. I am pondering to use it.

Can I route an URL for a HTML String through an API?
The idea is to create some static cache mechanism for heavy pages.
I would also need to remove or update the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding what you need, but wouldn't make more sense to use their already available [Cloud Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/)?

> **What it's good for**
>   Cloud Memorystore for Redis provides a fast, in-memory store for use cases that require fast, real-time processing of data. From simple caching use cases to real time analytics, Cloud Memorystore for Redis provides the performance you need.
>
> **Caching**: Cache is an integral part of modern application
>   architectures. Cloud Memorystore for Redis provides low latency access
>   and high throughput for heavily accessed data, compared to accessing
>   the data from a disk based backend store. Session management,
>   frequently accessed queries, scripts, and pages are common examples of
>   caching.